# convert chinese from the database to utf-8 chinese

Tags: php, sql-server

The characters in the database are showing  chinese characters but when queried from a phppage they show in special characters like " ³Â³¯Àû " ans not in chinese.

Comment: What you mean "from phppage"? Do you properly encode them in the HTML output?

Comment: a page with .php extention

Comment: Thanks. irrelevant comment. I mean, do you properly encode them for HTML? You make it sound like it is a database problem, I assume more you just throw hte string out and assuume the browser magically handles the bytes it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it show up in the right encoding when you manually override it in your browser? If so you might just need to set the appropriate encoding in your "Content-Type: ..." HTTP header.

If you can't change the encoding of the output and you need to force it to a specific encoding, you could use iconv - which is supported natively by PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

EDIT: just had a look, it looks like your data is encoded in 'GB2312'. So what should work is:

```
$yourstring=iconv('GB2312','UTF-8',$yourstring);
```

Comment: I have already tried everithing from iconv to htmlspecialchars() html_entitydecode(), htmlentities()
everytime it shows just like that

Comment: htmlspecialchars() won't do anything, that only encodes html syntax characters. html_entity_decode() has the exact opposite effect of what you're trying to do and htmlentities() is pretty much like htmlspecialchars(). iconv should work, but you need to feed it the right parameters for the conversion. That means you'll first have to find out what character encoding your string is in, then specify that and utf-8 as the output, then also specify utf-8 as the page encoding with the "Content-Type" header. Otherwise things will look garbled. Did you try setting the browser encoding?

Comment: yes i tried to change the browser encoding but still no use.
and if i set utf 8 in meta tag it again turns the page blank.

Comment: i tried the above iconv command but as the fetched string is speciel chars con it to uts 8 chanves it ti something else like this " é™ˆæœåˆ© "

Comment: Well, when I set it to 'GB2312' in firefox that string in the OP there works as expected. The second garbled string is *probably* in utf-8, try setting the browser encoding to that now.

Comment: No probs broham. Good luck ;)

Comment: Hello all i hace the same issue but this time with the american characters .
$yourstring=iconv('*','UTF-8',$yourstring);
tried many thins in the star but with no luck
Թալիա appears as Ô¹Õ¡Õ¬Õ«Õ¡

Comment: @Rushikesh that actually seems to be Armenian, not American. In theory it should work the same way, but iconv only supports input data in 'ARMSCII-8'. It might be a good idea to start a new question for this...